# How i can check if my Date Time field is less than Today() date inside JS script

Tags: javascript, development, list-view, jslink, js

I have the following JS script to color code our custom list items inside out list view, by checking if the item is status does not equal Delivered and its EndDate has been bypassed:-

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {
       function init() {
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
          Templates: {},
          OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
           var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
           for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
           {
              var currentDate = new Date();
              var enddate = rows[i]["EnDDate"];
              var status = rows[i]["OrderStatus"];
              var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
              var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
              if(row != null) {
                  if(status != 'Delivered' && enddate  && enddate < currentDate
                  )
                  {
                 row.style.backgroundColor = '#FA8072';
                 row.style.fontWeight = "bold";
                  }
```

now the above will not color code anything. the problem i think is that our `EndDate` field value will be return as follow `28/09/2018` while the `currentDate` will be retruned in the follow format `Tue Oct 09 2018 15:09:11 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)` .. so i think this will make my comparison `enddate < currentDate` return unexpected results! so can anyone advice on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is make your `enddate` variable a `Date` object that is based on the field value, like this:

```
var enddate = new Date(rows[i]["EnDDate"]); // is that really two capital Ds, or is that a typo?
```

I also see though that you are checking that `enddate` has a value, which means you are expecting that it might be blank?  In which case you might want to do something like:

```
var enddate = rows[i]["EnDDate"];
if (enddate) {
    enddate = new Date(enddate);
}

// and then later keep the same validation check:
if (status != 'Delivered' && enddate && enddate < currentDate)
```

---

If you are using a European format (day/month/year) you will need to swap the day and month, and if you are moving things around you might as well call the `Date` constructor with `year, month, date`, but if you do that you also have to keep in mind that in Javascript, months are zero-based.  So, if you are absolutely certain that the separators will be slashes, you could do:

```
var enddate = rows[i]["EnDDate"];
if (enddate) {
    var dateParts = enddate.split('/');
    enddate = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[0]); // subtract one from the month because in code it is zero-based
}
```

If you are not absolutely certain that your separators will be slashes, you will need more complex logic to separate the parts and swap things around.

Comment: but i am getting invalid date error .. where i added an alert as follow `alert(enddate)`.. not sure why ? altohugh the `enddate` variable will have this format `28/09/2018`

Comment: i also noted that the error will be on Firefox & chrome while on IE11 there will be no error,, but on IE11 if my EndDate value equal `28 August` after converting it to date it will be as follow `Wed Apr 8 00:00:00:00  UTC-0100 2020`...

Comment: @SharePointTestDev updated my answer, but also have a question for you: is the `EnDDate` field a text field, or is it a `DateTime` field?

Comment: will try your updated code... the EndDate is a  DateTime which only store Date without time and it uses friendly date to be displayed...

Comment: @SharePointTestDev sorry, I had a typo in my sample code, wrong array indexes in the wrong places.  Updated my answer to correct the typos.

Comment: thanks your updated code worked well for me,, but my last question can i make your code more robust, so it works if the user have the US-time format  (month/day/year) set on his machine? now in our case the sharepoint site itself is following the European format (day/month/year) but i can not guarantee the users' machine settings? can i inside JavaScript detect the user's machine time format, and build the dates values accordingly ?

Comment: To do that I would try just creating a new `Date` with the field value directly, like I originally suggested, like `enddate = new Date(enddate);`.  That will work for US format dates, but not for EU format, so then you would need to check whether `enddate` [is a valid date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1353711/988264), and if not, you know you have an EU format and need to rearrange it.

Comment: but i think `enddate = new Date(enddate)` will not always fail, i mean if the current date on the user machine is for example `11/28/2018`, then this date will be invalid based on the EU format, but if the date in the user machine is `02/05/2018` then this will work on both formats, but in US format the date will be in Feb while based on EU format it will be in May.. but the format will be valid.. so i mean i can not totally depend on creating the date as follow `enddate = new Date(enddate)` and then checks if the date is valid.. is my point correct or i am missing something?

Comment: Long day yesterday for me, I wasn't thinking straight, but yes, you are absolutely correct, there are certain dates that might be valid US format even though they are meant to be a different date in EU format. So... maybe that's a new question you can ask - how to detect what date format a user is seeing?  My guess is that if the SharePoint server is set to show a certain format, that's what everyone will see, their browser will not override that, but I couldn't say 100% certain.

Comment: you are correct that the dates within sharepoint will always be in EU format (as specified inside the site regional settings ).. but the problem is mainly when i am getting the current date/time `  var currentDate = new Date();` where i think this date will have the format as specified inside the user's machine,, and not as specified inside the sharepoint site.. is this correct?

Comment: Maybe, but that shouldn't matter.  `new Date()` will always give you "today, right now".  And once you have two valid `Date` objects that are set for the correct dates, you can make the `enddate < currentdate` comparison.  `Date` objects in and of themselves don't really have a "format", they are objects.  What's coming out of SharePoint as that field value is really a string though, which is why you have to convert it into a `Date` object in order to properly make the comparison.

Comment: so your original script is suppose to work well regardless of the user's machine date format ?

Comment: hi .. any advice on my above comment ?

Comment: I would think so, yes.  As I said, once you have two `Date` objects, "format" does not matter.